# how to get awstoken from AWS cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to use accessToken variable outside the success function. I tried different ways to use variable but it didn't work.

```js
var authenticationData = {
  Username : 'username',
  Password : 'password',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_ExaMPle',
  ClientId : '1example23456789'
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
  Username : 'username',
  Pool : userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
  onSuccess: function (result) {
    var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

    /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer */
    var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
  },

  onFailure: function(err) {
    alert(err);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the `accessToken` to the `authenticationData` object?

```js
var authenticationData = {
  Username : 'username',
  Password : 'password',
  AccessToken : ''
};

// And then set the token in the success method:
authenticationData.AccessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
```

Once `authenticationData.AccessToken` has been set, you can use the value anywhere in scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
This doesn't work for me. I tried to run the above mentioned but the problem is how to access the Token outside the class because if I run 
console.log(authenticationData.AccessToken)
outside the success method, the result is undefined.

Comment: Whether you put the token in the `authenticationData` object or a different object, the concept is still the same, re: save the token to something outside of the current scope so that it can be accessed in subsequent methods.